# Packing together javascript files a .NET Web Application

Tags: javascript, .net, razor, sprockets, nancy

I am writing a simple web app using NancyFX and the Razor view engine. I have little components in my web app that are having css, html and JavaScript. Each small component has its own folder in my Visual Studio solution.

When compiling I would like to pack together all the JavaScript code into one large file and include only that in my master-page. Something similar to ruby's sprocket gen would be the best.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you looked at Cassette? There is a Nuget package for integrating Cassette with Nancy.

Comment: Or SquishIt is another option that has Nancy support.

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal great recommendation. I will look into them. Thanks a lot! Krisztian

Comment: @StevenRobbins Cheers. I will check this one out too :)